# Animate Only Child Object

Tags: animation

I'd like to modify a child object without affecting its parent, but whenever I add a keyframe to the child object even location, rotation, etc. it affects the parent object as well.

Could I solve that somehow?

[image]

Comment: it should not affect the parent, maybe show some screenshots or share your file

Comment: I've updated the post with the .blend file.

Comment: actually you've keyframed the scale of the armature and the armature is the parent of the object called child, so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I want to modify only the *child* object. I've selected it and in this case, I scaled it down. But not only the *child* object got modified but also the armature. Should I do something else other than selecting the object?

Comment: you've given the same animation to both the child and the parent (armature), so the problem is not that the child make the parent scale down, the problem is that the animation makes the armature scale down

Comment: yes, but if I remove the scale transform from the armature it also removes from the child object

Comment: of course as they share the same action, you need to give 2 different actions to these 2 objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given the same action to both the child and the armature, if you switch the *Dope Sheet* to *Action Editor* mode and select the wand then the armature, you'll see that they share the same action. This action has some keyframes set for scale, so both the 2 objects scale down. It's not the wand that makes the armature scale down, it's the animation that is assigned to it:

[image]

If you want only the wand to scale down, duplicate the action (*New Action* button), remove the scale keyframes for the armature, keep them for the wand.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for me now!